# DataTable inserting only adds on row of value

Tags: c#, datatable

i have this dataTable where im storing airCraft information, but when i view the dataTable it only stores one entry from the xmlFile but all my xml files keep getting read and run trough, what can i do so that the dataTable gets all the information.

```
public DataTable Xmls(string aircraft, string Inspection, string IspectionDate, string path)
    {
        DataTable Xmls = new DataTable("AirCraftInfo");
        DataRow AirCraftRow = Xmls.NewRow();
        DataRow InspectionRow = Xmls.NewRow();
        DataRow InspectionDateRow = Xmls.NewRow();
        DataRow ImagePathRow = Xmls.NewRow();

        Xmls.Columns.Add("AirCraftRow", typeof(string));
        Xmls.Columns.Add("InspectionRow", typeof(string));
        Xmls.Columns.Add("InspectionDateRow", typeof(string));
        Xmls.Columns.Add("ImagePathRow", typeof(string));

        Xmls.Rows.Add(aircraft, Inspection, IspectionDate, path);

        return Xmls;
    }
```

---

```
       protected void GatherXmlInfo(string PathOfXml)
    {
        
        
        doc.Load(PathOfXml);

        AirCraft = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Document/Aircraft");
        Inspection = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Document/Inspection");
        InspectionDate = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Document/InspectionDate");


        aircraft = AirCraft.InnerText;

        inspection = Inspection.InnerText;

        inspectiondate = InspectionDate.InnerText;

        Xmls(aircraft, inspection, inspectiondate, PathOfXml);

    }
```

---

```
foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
            {

                ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

                filetmp = fileName;

                if (ext == ".tmp")
                {
                    SendFileTAP(filetmp, PathTipologia);

                }
                else if (ext != ".tmp")
                {
                    if (ext.ToUpper() == ".PDF" || ext.ToUpper() == ".XML")
                    {
                        CreateZips(filetmp);

                        if(ext.ToUpper() == ".XML")
                        {
                            GatherXmlInfo(filetmp);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not create one single method to create and fill the `DataTable`, you are overriding the data in it (storing only the last row in it).

```cs
public DataTable CreateTable()
{
    DataTable xmls = new DataTable("AirCraftInfo");

    xmls.Columns.Add("AirCraft", typeof(string));
    xmls.Columns.Add("Inspection", typeof(string));
    xmls.Columns.Add("InspectionDate", typeof(string));
    xmls.Columns.Add("ImagePath", typeof(string));

    return Xmls;
}

public void AddDataToTable(DataTable xmls, string aircraft, string inspection, string ispectionDate, string path)
{
    DataRow rowToAdd = xmls.NewRow();

    rowToAdd["AirCraft"] = aircraft;
    rowToAdd["Inspection"] = inspection;
    rowToAdd["InspectionDate"] = ispectionDate;
    rowToAdd["ImagePath"] = path;

    xmls.Rows.Add(rowToAdd);
}
```

And call it like this:

```cs
DataTable xmls = CreateTable();

foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
{
    string aircraft = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Document/Aircraft");
    string inspection = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Document/Inspection");
    string inspectionDate = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Document/InspectionDate");
    string path = "";

    AddDataToTable(xmls, aircraft, inspection, inspectionDate, path);
}
```